# The apostrophe sign in informal shortened phrases

Tags: grammar, slang, apostrophe

There are certain informal expressions in English language like *'nuff said* or *'Murican* that feature apostrophes in a puzzling (to me) way. I have two (I think sufficiently related) questions about the usage of apostrophe in such cases.

Firstly, what purpose is it supposed to serve? When we write *John's house*, apostrophe signifies that house belongs to John; but in such phrases what does apostrophe signify?

Secondly, is the apostrophe supposed to be pronounced in any way (or is *'Murican* pronounced the same as *Murican*)?

Comment: The apostrophe serves two purposes in English orthography: the genitive, as you mention, and a marker for elision of letters, as in *can’t*, *couldn’t*, PE in your cases *enough* and *American*. It’s telling you there’s a letter or letters there that has/have been elided. And since they’re elided, no, you don’t pronounce them.

Comment: The purpose of an apostrophe is simply to indicate that something is missing. "John's car" means "John, his car". At least that was what I was taught at school about 60 years ago. I think modern linguistics scholars may take a different view.

Comment: @DanBron The possessive apostrophe also signifies missing letters. It’s just that in this specific case, the letters have been missing for several centuries.

Comment: One accepted abbreviation of _forecastle_ is _fo'c'sle_, where the second apostrophe shows that a letter (_a_) is missing but the first must just be taken as indicating that _letter/s_ is/are missing. That it is possible that an apostrophe can just have the meaning << Caution: letters missing hereabouts >> is shown by the fact that the _t_ may be dropped unannounced (though sometimes, a third apostrophe is inserted). From your examples, perhaps << Caution: letters missing hereabouts, with possible weird spelling variations >> is perhaps more accurate at times.

Comment: ... Other than as relating to these strange words, there are hundreds of questions on the use of the apostrophe on ELU.

Comment: @WS2: In the genitive 's, the apostrophe marks the missing "e" of the "es" genitive suffix in singular masculine and neuter nouns in Old English.

Comment: Some of this is style rather than grammar. Not so long ago you might "use the 'phone to book a seat on a 'plane while drinking a  cold beer you had taken from the 'frig'." Such pedantry in indicating omitted letters would now seem absurd, and, in my opinion was absurd pedantry even then, but it was commonly used.

Comment: @Greybeard How do you know that? Is there some historical scholarship available which endorses this idea?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which explains why Southampton gets abbreviated to So'ton in the football league tables.

Comment: @ WS2: Yes, there is plenty of scholarship on OE and OE verbs. I suggest using "Google Scholar".

Comment: @Greybeard Can you quote the particular reference that says the genitive apostrophe marks the missing "e" of "es". If there is, I would be glad to know where they got it from.